# How can I find all keys from each json file and output it as a dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, json, dataframe, key

Suppose I have "n" json files. The first 4 are fetched below:

'path/file1.json'

```
{"keyA":"valueA",
"keyB":"valueB",
"keyC":"valueC",
"keyD":{
    "keyD_1":"valueD_1",
    "KeyD_2":"valueD_2"
    }
}
```

'path/file2.json'

```
{"keyB":"valueB",
"keyC":"valueC",
"keyD":{
    "KeyD_2":"valueD_2"
    }
}
```

'path/file3.json'

```
{"keyA":"valueA",
"keyB":"valueB",
"keyD":{
    "keyD_1":"valueD_1",
    "KeyD_2":"valueD_2"
    }
}
```

'path/file4.json'

```
{"keyB":"valueB",
"keyD":{
    "KeyD_1":"valueD_1"
    }
}
```

Using python, I want to generate a table (dataframe) with the keys as columns and the file names as rows. I want each row to have value "1" in a key column whenever such key is in the JSON file, "0" otherwise. So, for the example above, I need the following output:

```
file_name   keyA    keyB    keyC    keyD    keyD_1  keyD_2
file1.json  1       1       1       1       1       1
file2.json  0       1       1       1       0       1
file3.json  1       1       0       1       1       1
file4.json  0       1       0       1       1       0
(...)       (...)   (...)   (...)   (...)   (...)   (...)
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Best,

Nigel

Answer (score 1):

You can load the contents of the files into a dictionary (keys are filenames, values are the data inside the files) and then create the dataframe:

```py
files = {
    "file1.json": {
        "keyA": "valueA",
        "keyB": "valueB",
        "keyC": "valueC",
        "keyD": {"keyD_1": "valueD_1", "KeyD_2": "valueD_2"},
    },
    "file2.json": {"keyB": "valueB", "keyC": "valueC", "keyD": {"KeyD_2": "valueD_2"}},
    "file3.json": {
        "keyA": "valueA",
        "keyB": "valueB",
        "keyD": {"keyD_1": "valueD_1", "KeyD_2": "valueD_2"},
    },
    "file4.json": {"keyB": "valueB", "keyD": {"KeyD_1": "valueD_1"}},
}

all_data = []
for data in files.values():
    all_data.append({**{k: 1 for k in data}, **{k: 1 for k in data["keyD"]}})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, index=files.keys()).fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            keyA  keyB  keyC  keyD  keyD_1  KeyD_2  KeyD_1
file1.json     1     1     1     1       1       1       0
file2.json     0     1     1     1       0       1       0
file3.json     1     1     0     1       1       1       0
file4.json     0     1     0     1       0       0       1
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, thank you. Indeed the solution works fine, but let's pretend I have a number of json files that is too large (e.g. more than 100 json files). Can you think of another (automated) way to load the file contents into the dictionary? p.s.> also, column KeyD_1 is duplicated but with different values.

Comment: @NigelBlainey Yes, you can use `os` module or `glob` module to load the files in automatic way.